# custom user creation form dosent save password in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

hello guys in django i tryed to make a simple custom user creation form extends as UserCreationForm .everything works but after save the record in database dont have password and i dont know why is that happening.
help me plz

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.TextInput()
    last_name = forms.TextInput()
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('username','email','first_name','last_name','password1','password2')

    def save(self,commit=True):
         user=super(UserCreationForm,self).save(commit=False)
         user.email=self.cleaned_data['email']
         user.first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name']
         user.last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name']
         if commit:
             user.save()
         return user
```

and in the view the code is :

```
def register_user_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/success')
    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form']=MyRegistrationForm().as_ul()
    print(args)
    return render_to_response('register.html',args)
def register_succesfull_view(request):
    return render_to_response('registersucc.html')
```

[in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DrEd.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the *current* class, not the parent class, in the call to `super`:

```
user=super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
```

The way you had it meant that it was skipping the parent and going straight to the grandparent, ie ModelForm, which doesn't have the custom set_password logic.

Note though that since you are using Python 3 you don't need any parameters to super at all:

```
user=super().save(commit=False)
```

which would have avoided your problem.